# Error LNK1104 when upgrade from VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-errors, upgrade

My project make C dll deployment in Matlab.

After upgrade from VS C++ 2008 to VS C++ 2010 project, I got this error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc90d.lib'
```

After searching for solution, I think it should reference to 'mfc100d.lib'. But I don't know **HOW** to reference.

I tried to reference 'mfc90d.lib', and 'mfc100d.lib'. After that, the error gone, and the other replaced.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfcs90d.lib'
```

Even when I put 'mfcs90d.lib' in library paths, nothing happen. The error still there.

Does anyone meet that problem? And how you solve that?

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you have recompiled all of the dependencies with Visual Studio 2010. This will occur if one or more of your dependencies were compiled with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @drescherjm: Maybe one of my header file was built with VS2008.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: sure, but I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment >_<

Comment: Leave a comment for what?  That question has an answer that might help you.  If you already tried everything listed there and have a different problem you should say so in this question and provide details for what you have already tried, otherwise it looks like a pretty clear duplicate.

Comment: I don't know how to reference 'mfc90d.lib', not ask for solution about the error.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2010 you want to make sure that none of your dependencies are pulling in Visual Studio 2008. Fixing the error by putting mfc90d.lib in your library paths is the wrong solution. This will lead to more than 1 version of MFC being used at the same time and most likely lead to random crashes if it works at all.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I mean 'mfc100d.lib'.

Comment: `Sorry, my mistake. I mean 'mfc100d.lib'.` I would say most likely this is not your problem. I suspect that the real problem is your project is dependent on both mfc90d.lib and mfc100d.lib. If this is the case you need to remove the dependency on mfc90d.lib by recompiling all of the dependencies with Visual Studio 2010.